# how to make all items in an adapter clickable?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I made an app following a tutorial. The creator of the tutorial made a "Recents" row which contains photos of the places you can go to.
The code was made to show the same "details activity" every time you click on a photo.

The problem: I already made 4 different Activities to each photo in the recents row and I want to link each photo to its Activity.

[the DetailsActivity that keeps on showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI3oF.jpg)
[Recents-row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E12r.jpg)

```java
public class RecentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecentsAdapter.RecentsViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<RecentsData> recentsDataList;
    //the RecentsAdapter code:

    public RecentsAdapter(Context context, List<RecentsData> recentsDataList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.recentsDataList = recentsDataList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecentsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recents_row_item, parent ,false);
        return new RecentsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecentsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.countryName.setText(recentsDataList.get(position).getCountryName());
        holder.placeName.setText(recentsDataList.get(position).getPlaceName());
        holder.price.setText(recentsDataList.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.placeImage.setImageResource(recentsDataList.get(position).getImageUrl());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recentsDataList.size();
    }

    public static final class RecentsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView placeImage;
        TextView placeName,countryName,price;
        public RecentsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            placeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_image);
            placeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_name);
            countryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want? As I understand you can directly put condition on click based on ID,name or anything you want and you can map it to the particular activity

Comment: Can you also share your XML and also on which you want to add onclick

Answer (score 1):

Pass extra arguments in your click listener:

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecentsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DataItem item = recentsDataList.get(position); //Cleaner code

    holder.countryName.setText(item.getCountryName());
    holder.placeName.setText(item.getPlaceName());
    holder.price.setText(item.getPrice());
    holder.placeImage.setImageResource(item.getImageUrl());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
            
            //You can add more arguments here
            i.putExtra("place_name", item.getPlaceName());

            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

And in your DetailsActivity.onCreate():

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    //Get the place name and load the layout accordingly
    String placeName = getIntent().getStringExtra("place_name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an intent to convey a message. You can use `intent.putExtra()`

If you want to pass a bundle, you can use `intent.putExtras()`